# Magento Search issues

Tags: magento, web

I am having some search issues with our Megento Store.
We are trying to add spelling differences to our store so when someone spells a product name wrong in our search bar it displays the product they are searching for.

At first I thought this will be a doddle simply go to Catalog > Search Terms > Click on the product and add a Synonym for it.... However this didn't work.

If it helps our store can be found here: http://bit.ly/aOZqBv and the search bar can be found at the top right hand side of the screen.

As a an example of a product search term we are trying to generate a product result for is a follows: If a user searches for a work *optimise* we want our website to then display results for the product *optimeyes*.

I believe at the early dev stage of this website the search bar was altered in some way from a basic search box which would display seemingly random results when searching for a product, to the advanced search box to deliver better results.

I think this issues may require some code to make the change rather than just a simple fix via the admin panel, but what this code looks like I am unsure.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

P.s Magento ver. 1.7.0.0

Comment: Are you adding the search alias the right way around? I.e. You are going to the search result `optimise` and adding the synonym `optimeyes`, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the response. Yes I can confirm that I've placed the search alias the correct way around.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the Catalog search settings are currently set to _Full Text_.

Answer (score 1):

Stock Magento does not allow to include misspellings automatically. You might want to add some popular misspellings of your products to the list of keywords and include the keywords to the search index.

Alternatively you can check out the [Advanced Search extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-search-with-auto-complete-and-weighted-attributes.html), it allows to add "search similarity" i.e. looking also for similarly sounding or misspelled versions of your search keywords based on the words' "soundex" index.